# How to use javascript namespaces?

Tags: javascript, javascript-namespaces

I am trying to figure out JavaScript namespaces... I would like to write couple of functions and secure them in namespaces like below.. but I think I don't get it very well..This is too simple question but it will be clear for me I guess If I see why that doesn't work..

Here an exp that I am trying:

```
var myApp = { 
    getTxt: function(x){
        x.click(function(){
        var txt = $(this).html();
        alert(txt);
        });
    };    
};
```

call myApp:

```
var box = $('.js-box');
alert(myApp.getTxt(box));
```

I think MyApp is created rightly but I am not sure about calling and firing the getTxt function..

Calling that:

```
  myApp.getTxt(box)
```

doesn't mean to fire x.click function..? Why does it turn an object?

What am I doing wrong here? Thanx!

http://jsfiddle.net/67b02cht/1/

Comment: Why do you think you are doing something wrong? Which problem do you encounter?

Comment: You show what you're doing, but you don't say what you're seeing or what you're expecting. Could you add more info?

Comment: I think I don't call it right...?

Comment: Again: why? Is something happening that you don't expect? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining `myApp` as an object, So here is a problem, You are giving `;` after defining the field, which you can't. It'll cause a syntax error.

```
var myApp = { 
    getTxt: function(x){
        x.click(function(){
        var txt = $(this).html();
        alert(txt);
        });
    }                //<<<<-------------here was a semicolon,
};
```

And you are calling the function like bellow in `alert` it will cause an `undefined` alert because you are not returning anything from the function. Just call

```
myApp.getTxt(box)
```

And it will show the content on click.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/78/)

Comment: Oke that s right but I still get undefined.. why is that?

Comment: @rene mostly it does but in some cases, it doesn't & this is one of them.

Comment: @Mar I didn't get what is `this.txt`?

Comment: Sorry:) a fault! Thnx for the demo! I get it now! I alert in my getTxt function and When I call it alert again..

Answer (score 0):

How about a modular approach.

```
var MyApp = MyApp || {};
MyApp.Module = (function () {
  function App() {
  }
  App.prototype.getTxt = function(x){
    //your code here
  }
  return App;
})();
```

Use it this way:

```
var box = $('.js-box');    
alert(new MyApp.Module.getTxt(box));
```